# Windows Form How to output command results to textbox

Tags: powershell, windows-forms-designer

I'm very new to Windows Form, so please keep this in mind. I did spend many hours searching and looking for answers (as one should before asking).

So my question is I'm trying to display Powershell result outputs to a text box. My script has radio buttons that give the options to check user AD account status, unlock account, disable and so on. They select the radio within the "groupbox" and then hit the start button. I then want to display the command output to the text box. So for example, I should be able to display Get-Aduser filtered results to textbox.

Here is an example of my ending function (I haven't added all future radio buttons to it yet):

```
Function StartOptions
{ 
$User=$InputBox.text 
  If ($Domain1Button.checked -eq $true) {$Domain = "Domain1"}
  If ($Domain2Button.checked -eq $true) {$Domain = "Domain2"}
  If ($UserStatusButton.checked -eq $true) {Get-ADUser -identity $User -Server $Domain -Properties * | Select-Object SamAccountName,Name,LockedOut,Enabled,EmailAddress,PasswordLastSet|Format-Table}
  $outputBox.Text= (Not sure what to put here to Output the results of Aduser)
  
  }
```

An Example of Groupbox:

```
#GROUPBOX Domain Selection
$groupBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.GroupBox 
$groupBox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,90) 
$groupBox1.size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(175,37) 
$groupBox1.text = "Choose a Domain:" 
$Form.Controls.Add($groupBox1)
```

An example of Radio Button:

```
$Domain1Button= New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RadioButton
$Domain1Button.Location = '15,15'
$Domain1Button.size = '72,20'
$Domain1Button.Checked = $true
$Domain1Button.Text = "Domain1"
$groupBox1.Controls.Add($Domain1Button)
```

Please forgive me if this is a dumb question. I really am trying to learn.

Thank you so much.

Comment: You aren't assigning the results that you get from Get-AdUser to anything right now. So you will want to do something like $getUserResults = Get-ADUser -identity $User -Server $Domain etc....

Then you can work with the information you just grabbed elsewhere in the script. Does that help?

Comment: Programming/Scripting languages notwithstanding, this is a very common thing to do and not anything unique to PowerShell. You simply directly assign the output to the Text property of the form object. Just as you do with variables, yet, with forms, you use from events, and the event is your code as an action. There hundreds of examples (text and Youtube videos) of this all over the web. What did you searhc for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment above...

Ther are lots of examples all over the web and [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell%20gui) for this use case since it's a common, well before PowerShell was ever a thing. This is all about knowing about and using 'Form Events'.

> [Events Overview (Windows Forms)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/events-overview-windows-forms)
>
> ['PowerShell assign command output to a winform text box'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27powershell%20assign%20comand%20output%20to%20a%20winfomr%20text%20box%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20assign%20comand%20output%20to%20a%20winfomr%20text%20box%27&sc=0-55&sk=&cvid=61769AC7215A428DACF9AB20F24CDE99)
>
> [Displaying Output in a GUI Application](https://www.sapien.com/blog/2014/12/15/display-output-in-a-gui-application-copy/)

```
$buttonComputerName_Click = {
    $textboxResults.Text = $env:ComputerName
}
```

Or

> [How to execute a script from a Windows Form and capture the output in a text box](https://info.sapien.com/index.php/how-to/powershell-studio-howto/simply-execute-script-and-output-to-the-form)

There are modules in the MS powershellgallery.com, for building WinForm/WPF GUI's ...

```
Find-Module -Name '*gui*'
Find-Module -Name '*form*'
```

... just install and use them.

There is also, this free website for PowerShell GUI development.

> https://poshgui.com

Comment: Thank you. I finally got it working. The references you gave me are a help, especially the find-mole! Now, this is useful!

Comment: No worries. We all had to start from somewhere, and it is always a state of ABL (always be learning), no matter how much one thinks they know, there is always more, even for stuff one thinks they may already know.